# How to validate one field by another in a model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

On saving data to the model I want to validate one field by another (they are in the same model). Here is my model:

```
class String(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=230)
    maxSize = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I want to validate `value` field by max size taken from the `maxSize` field and return specific error to user when validation is failed. How to do that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add your own validation method in model form

```
class FormString(forms.ModelField):
    class Meta:
        model = String
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean_value(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get("value")
        max_size = self.cleaned_data.get("maxSize")
        if value and max_size and len(value) > max_size:
            self.add_error("value", "length should be less then {}".format(max_size))
        return value
```

or you can have validation in your clean method

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    value = cleaned_data.get('value')
    max_size = cleaned_data.get("maxSize")
    if value and max_size and len(value) > max_size:
        self.add_error("value", "length should be less then {}".format(max_size))
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: `self.add_error()` going to work same as `raise ValidationError()` but for specified field, right?

Comment: don't you know why `cleaned_data` could not contain my `max_size` - `PositiveSmallIntegerField`? It gives me other field but not `max_size`. Sorry for the off-topic question

Comment: try to use validation in `clean` method. i added it to answer. and don't forget that you don't have `max_size` field, you have `maxSize`

Comment: I changed maxSize to max_size everywhere, that's fine.

Comment: yes, this works fine, but I don't understand why this works this way.. if I use `clean_value` is gives me all field exclude of one `max_size`, but with `clean` method it works fine. This world is strange. Anyway thx a lot

Comment: we can't define order on which clean_`field` is called. so there could be a situation when `clean_maxSize` is called after `clean_value` so in `clean_value` method we don't have clean value of `maxSize`, so it's better to use `clean` method when you have dependences between fields

Comment: Oh, now I see that. Thx bro :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `ModelForm` You can use the [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method.

```
class StringModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        # Everything as before.

        def clean(self):
          cleaned_data = super().clean()
          maxSize = cleaned_data.get("maxSize")
          value = cleaned_data.get("value")
          
          if maxSize = ... : #you logic here 
              raise ValidationError('your error message')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a form see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). When raising a ValidationError you can inform the user with a custom message.

Comment: OP talked about models here, not forms.